# Query unexpectedly returns no rows

Tags: oracle, siebel

I am trying to return a list of cell phone numbers from the `S_CONTACT` table of Siebel where the value contains anything other than numbers.

The query I am using is:

```
select cell_ph_num 
from s_contact
where regexp_replace(cell_ph_num, '0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9', '') <> ''
```

But I get no results.

However, when I run the following query:

```
select regexp_replace(cell_ph_num, '0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9', '') from s_contact
```

I get a load of results.

Do these results not match the "does not equal empty string" clause?

Comment: `where regexp_like(cell_ph_num, '\D')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`''` is `NULL` in oracle.. so it has to be `IS NOT NULL`

```
select cell_ph_num 
from s_contact
where regexp_replace(cell_ph_num, '0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9', '') IS NOT NULL
```

OR We can use `REGEXP_LIKE` this way by `POSIX` class

```
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (cell_ph_num,'[^[:DIGIT:]]');
```

OR *Perl* style `POSIX` equivalent

```
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (cell_ph_num,'\D');
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew that '' and NULL were "the same" in Oracle but why does <> '' not work?

Comment: `NULL`s cannot be used with any relational operator. Only IS NULL or `IS NOT NULL` is allowed.. Else you have to use `NVL()`